# How do I make a PHP page display when the MySQL table was last updated?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL db, table with data that loads from a source every 2 - 4 hours, I am currently typing when the table was last updated. Currently it is updated with `load data local infile replace into mytable` so the data loads automatically with cron, I just want to display below the html table when the data was last updated.

[image]

I have tried update_time and information.schema, but doesn't display anything it just displays blank in the area I would like it to appear.

Here is a query I have tried which seems simplest, and preferable, but only displays BLANK white page.

```
<?php 
    $connection = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'password'); 
    mysql_select_db('db'); 
    $query= "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'count_page'"; $result=mysql_query($query);
    if (mysql_num_rows($results)> 0) {  
        $rst=mysql_fetch_arry($result); print $rst['Update_time']; 
    } else {
        print 'These arent the droids youre looking for'; 
    } 
    mysql_close(); 
?>
```

Comment: you can always punt and have a simple table that contains a single "last_updated" field that you update whenever your `load infile` completes.

Comment: Sadly creation of new Tables is restricted as this time, at my current location. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make text file which contains the last updated date. Add this to your cron file:

```
file_put_contents('date.txt', date('m/d/Y/g:iA'));
```

Then put this to your table showing script where you want to add last updated date.

```
echo '<b>Data Last Updated : (' . file_get_contents("date.txt") . ')</b>';
```

You can always put extra timestamp column to your table and use it, but this is one approach.

Comment: I would prefer a SQL query or something along these lines, where I'm at they are very restricted on creating and editing existing crons.

Comment: Try to add `or die(mysql_error())` to your `mysql_query` function and tell what it says. `$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: I am getting my else message. "These aren't the droids you are looking for."

Comment: Anyone else have some more insight on the issue? My else statement is now displaying instead of blank page.

Comment: Try to change `mysql_num_rows($results)> 0` to `mysql_num_rows($result)> 0`. You have specified that name to query variable.